# how to Check for equality with list input in linq

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

these are my dtos

---

```
public class CreateTenantDto
{
    public Guid TenantId { get; set; }
    public List<CreateTenantSectionDto> TenantSections { get; set; }
}
public class CreateTenantSectionDto
{
    public Guid SectionId { get; set; }
    public List<CreateTenantProperties> TenantProperties { get; set; }
}
public class CreateTenantProperties
{
    public Guid PropertyId { get; set; }
    public string QuantityName { get; set; }
}
```

---

This is my service where i use linq and i want to check sections equality with input list of section id

```
public async Task<bool> AddTenant(CreateTenantDto dto)
{
  var personSectionList = await _personFormSectionDetailRepository.Query()
        .Filter(x => x.Id == ??? ).GetAllAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding you have a list of string which is `TenantSections` and you want to retrieve all the tenants that each Id of it is within `TenantSections` in the DTO, if that is exactly what you are aiming for then you should use .Contains() to achieve that as following:

```
    public async Task<bool> AddTenant(CreateTenantDto dto)
    {
        var personSectionList = await _personFormSectionDetailRepository.Query()
                .Filter(x => dto.TenantSections.Contains(x.Id)).GetAllAsync();
      return personSectionList.Any();
    }
```

What `.Contains()` does in this case is to check if each Id of the Tenants is actually contained with the provided list in the parameter

**UPDATED:**

I have updated the code above to add the check if there is data returned or no using the `.Any()` method

Comment: There is No Access check with sections dto its not work

Comment: Could you explain more about No Access check please?

Comment: I have updated the answers to check if the query returns items or no